# Converting 'resize' eventListener from class to functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn React-Hooks so I wrote a little function that shows the width of the window in real time:

Class component:

```
state = { windowWidth: window.innerWidth }

handleResize = () => this.setState({ windowWidth: window.innerWidth });
handleEvent = () => window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);

componentDidMount = () => this.handleEvent();
componentWillUnmount = () => this.handleEvent();

/* using { this.state.windowWidth } */
```

I tried to convert this to a functional component with React-Hooks, but it didn't work for me. What was wrong?

Functional component:

```
const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

const handleResize = () => setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
}, []);

/* using { windowWidth } */
```

Comment: What happens if you add a console.log inside another useEffect block with windowWidth as a dependency? Do you see it update in the console?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what happens and what the problem is in your current code? I tried it in code sandbox and it works just fine. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/little-lake-fgcvd?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
I use it all the time. Remember to cleanup the eventListener after unmount. You have to return `.off` inside the useEffect.

```
import $ from 'jquery'

const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

function handleResize() {
    try {
        setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    $(window).on('resize', handleResize);
    return () => {
        $(window).off('resize', handleResize);
    };
}, []);
```